# ASP.NET C#, returning objects to Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angular

I am writing a C# api backend for an Angular front end. I have done this before in other projects and previously I have always just returned an object from the c# and in postman or Angular I was able to read the object. In postman, it was neatly formatted as json.

For example, I used to have a `class Person` and a controller `PersonController`.  In `PersonController`, I could have a method `Get()` and the Get would be like this

```
public Person Get() {
    Person p = new Person();
    ...
    return p;
}
```

and I should call the `PersonController.Get` from Angular and I would have the person. However for some reason, now I am doing this in a new project and all I am getting is `[Person]` -- not the expandable json.

Why is this?

I know I see that a diff. developer has spent time to return it as a string:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer()
            {
                MaxJsonLength = 3000;
            };
strJson = json.Serialize(model);
return strJson;
```

But I want to return the actual object. I find parsing it made it much much slower.

EDIT:

This is my actual controller:

```
 public class PersonController : Controller
 {
        private readonly IPersonService personService;

        public PersonController()
        {
            presonService =  new PersonService();
        }

        public async Task<JArray> Get(int? id)
        {
            var model = await personService.GetInfo(id, ConnHelper.ConnectionString());
            JArray a = (JArray)JToken.FromObject(model);
            return a;
            //return model;
        }

        public async Task<List<Person>> GetObject(int? id)
        {
                var model = await personService.GetInfo(id, ConnHelper.ConnectionString());                
                return model;
        }
}
```

Comment: show us your controller method

Comment: I did.  I wrote it out exactly the same idea.

Comment: Edit your question and include that controller action

Comment: it's there:public Person Get(){
Person p = new Person();
...
return p;
}

Comment: Where did you find that code of serialize?

Comment: where does `model` variable comes from? What is its type?

Comment: As requested, provide your controller code. This is a rehash of your other question where you were getting a string value. Your controller code matters because it is what returns data to _any_ front end client - _how_ it does that is the issue. You'll also have to provide your client code and _how_ it's sending the request because it matters. If _"you've done this before"_ then you know why they both matter.

Comment: I have updated my question with the actual controller now.  The Get returning the   JArray works but the GetObject does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your controller is a normal controller you should return Json as below:

```
public class PersonController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonService personService;

    public PersonController()
    {
        presonService =  new PersonService();
    }


    public async Task<JArray> Get(int? id)
    {
        var model = await personService.GetInfo(id, ConnHelper.ConnectionString());
        JArray a = (JArray)JToken.FromObject(model);
        return Json(a);
        //return model;
    }




public async Task<List<Person>> GetObject(int? id)
            {
                var model = await personService.GetInfo(id, ConnHelper.ConnectionString());                
                return Json(model);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean a normal controller as opposed to what kind of other controller could it be?

Comment: also what class is that Json?  I tried it and get error:  Cannot convert json... to type List<Person>...

Comment: Opposed to ApiController

Comment: Json is not a class, it is a function like View() which is used for normal view

Comment: I think the issue is with data not json function. Are you sure GetInfo is returning array? as it has an id as parameter, I believe it is returning only one item

Comment: I got your bottom one working, if I change the returntype of getobject to JsonResult @mehrdad Babaki

Answer (score 0):

When you only need to support JSON in your ASP.NET Web API, in your Global.asax inside Application_Start(), add this

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

I think this will be a good place to dig:
https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/

Comment: this did not help actually.

Comment: any other ideas  @Praneet Nadkar

Comment: What happened when you added this code? You did not get a JSON response?
You can convert your object types to json in your action filter. Check this: https://gist.github.com/brainded/8698865 to see how to convert object to JSON.

Comment: but that static class is just helping return the object as string (Json string, but string)  I want to return the object and handle the parsing in javascript/angular.

Comment: Why do you want to parse in JS or angular? angular understands json right? You want to pass the structure